# How to form the IV and Additional Data for TLS when encrypting the plaintext

Tags: tls, authentication, openssl, aes, aead

When using AES GCM for encryption within TLS and referring to the below diagram:

1. Is iv[0:3] the fixed IV established from the handshake and iv[4:11] are the current (write) sequence number + 1?
2. For TLS 1.2 the additional data is `type || legacy_record_version || length`?
3. But for TLS 1.3 the additional data is `seq_num || type || legacy_record_version || length`?
4. Are points 2 and 3 the only difference between TLS 1.2 and 1.3 when encrypting the plaintext? Not during the handshake, just the plaintext encryption.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> Is iv[0:3] the fixed IV established from the handshake and iv[4:11] are the current (write) sequence number + 1?

Mostly not. [In TLS1.2, the GCM nonce](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288#page-3) is 4 bytes generated from the handshake plus 8 bytes *in (the beginning of) the transmitted record*. The sender must make this 8-byte `nonce_explicit` unique, and *some* implementations make it a counter because that's a cheap and safe way to make it unique. (Unlike IV for CBC it does NOT need to be unpredictable.) [In TLS1.3 for GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#section-5.3) the nonce is *12* bytes generated from the handshake *XORed with* the (8-byte, right-aligned) sequence number.

> For TLS 1.2 the additional data is type || legacy_record_version || length

No; it is [seqnum || type || version || length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-25). (In 1.2 the record header version is the real version; only in 1.3 does it become legacy.)

> But for TLS 1.3 the additional data is seq_num || type || legacy_record_version || length?

No again; now it's [type || version || length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#page-81) using the 'opaque' (outer) type (not the one within the encryption), the 'legacy' (record header) version, and the length *including* the 'hidden' (inner) type and any padding plus the AEAD algorithm's 'expansion', which for rfc5116-style GCM is the 16-byte tag. Because nonce now depends on seqnum always regardless of ciphersuite and AEAD protects nonce, seqnum isn't needed in AAD.